Delete Duplicate Files Across Multiple Servers
I work in academia. We have three Linux servers where many users read, write, and create files all the time. Over the years, the servers have become bloated, with many files copied among multiple directories and across all three servers.
Is there an application that runs on Linux that can safely delete all the duplicate files? Ideally, it would replace the deleted files with a symlink pointing to the original file.

As far as I know a conventional Linux symlink can only contain a file system path and not a server name/address, you can link to /path/to/nfs/or/other/share/ but not to servername-or-IP/path/to/file - Second, your users might be surprised, and not in a good way, when they thought they were working with a copy of the original data when they suddenly modified/deleted the (only) original version. - A safer result is a file system/storage solution  that does de-duplication on the block level, rather than somebody who, however well intentioned, "cleans up" the file servers.

That was a long paragraph to say: "I can't imagine any program/circumstance where deleting files that belong to other users is 100% safe and won't lead to unwanted dataloss.  - But maybe I lack imagination. - Regardless make backups and test and verify your restore procedures before you even attempt anything like this.

ZFS dedupe is block level - a VERY different thing from file level de-duplication.

And this will work on ONE server and do not delete duplications on all 3 servers

@AlexandruIliescu, you start to change significantly the infra. Also dedup need good amount of memory and processor power. So IMHO your solution (for the OP case) is bad, very bad
